# SVG path convert into JSON

Tags: javascript, json, svg

I have this path:

```
<path id="secnb1l1" class="lungon"
    fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
    d="M 93.00,444.00
       C 93.00,444.00 114.00,506.00 114.00,506.00
         102.30,512.28 100.00,518.71 100.00,531.00
         100.00,531.00 86.00,534.00 86.00,534.00
         86.00,534.00 68.95,485.00 68.95,485.00
         68.95,485.00 58.00,452.00 58.00,452.00
         58.00,452.00 93.00,444.00 93.00,444.00 Z
       M 75.00,458.00
       C 75.00,458.00 79.00,458.00 79.00,458.00
         78.99,466.29 79.26,463.93 76.00,471.00
         76.00,471.00 86.00,471.00 86.00,471.00
         82.12,462.60 83.00,464.37 83.00,455.00
         83.00,455.00 75.00,458.00 75.00,458.00 Z" />
```

And I want to convert it into JSON. Just like on this [**LINK**](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js)

quick example of SVG converted into JSON:

(SVG):

```
<path d=" M 10 25
        L 10 75
        L 60 75
        L 10 25"
        stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
```

(JSON):

```
var lineData = [ { "x": 1,   "y": 5},  { "x": 20,  "y": 20},
             { "x": 40,  "y": 10}, { "x": 60,  "y": 40},
             { "x": 80,  "y": 5},  { "x": 100, "y": 60}];
```

I'm afraid that there's no generator to make my works easier. It's a pain to convert it manually.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

**EDIT**

I'm using d3.js for zoom and pan.

Comment: How do you expect the curves to appear in the JSON.  As many co-ordinates or with a "path type" attribute for each co-ord?

Comment: @richieahb, I tried the with `path type`, I don't know but this don't appear in my html. So I think I need the `coordinates`. Thanks for you response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to fiddle around with string operations, you can also use the DOM Interface.

[Interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#DOMInterfaces)

[PathSegList](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegList)

From there you can iterate over the path elements path segments list and create a json string from that.

```
var path = document.getElementById(<pathid>),
    seglist = path.pathSegList,
    length = seglist.numberOfItems, i = 0, seg,
    out = [], data, type;


for (; i < length; i++) {
    seg = seglist.getItem(i);
    type = seg.pathSegTypeAsLetter;
    data = { type: seg.pathSegTypeAsLetter };

    switch (type) {
        case 'M':
        case 'm':
        case 'l' :
        case 'L' :
            data.x = seg.x;
            data.y = seg.y;
        break;

        case 'C':
        case 'c':
            data.x = seg.x;
            data.y = seg.x;
            data.x1 = seg.x1;
            data.y1 = seg.y1;
            data.x2 = seg.x2;
            data.y2 = seg.y2;
        break;
        /*
         * to
         * be
         * continued
         */
    }
    out.push(data);
}

return JSON.stringify(out);
```

I have not test the code above, it should outline the basic process of iterating the Paths' segments. Since there are quite a couple of different types of segments, you can, as outlines above, »switch« over the type and create suitable data from there. Or, instead of `path.pathSegList` you could use `path.normalizedPathSegList` what return a list of segments, where each segment is converted to the type of cubic Bezier, but when tried it the last time, I got an »Not yet implemented Error«.

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yprgsvk7/) showing that the code works!

Comment: Done reading and my nose is bleeding right now. I'm newbie in SVG and JSON, plus,  I'm a visual learner. Can you please provide example using my path above? :)

Comment: This code assumes absolute path commands.  It would need to be modified if the source path uses relative path commands (the lower case ones).

Comment: Obviously there are a lot cases missing in the switch statement, but that is just a matter of ambition... The conversion from relative to absolute is easy to implement, only one variable for the last coordinates needs to be maintained and added if necessary. But right now the code above is just reading the data, no matter if relative or absolute.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you haven't specified things such as resolution etc. for your path around curves, I've just created a JSON with an extra property for the path type from that co-ordinate to the next one.

```
var d = document.getElementById('secnb1l1').getAttribute('d');

d = d.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' '); // Remove multiple spaces
d = d.replace(/([a-zA-Z])\s[0-9]/g, '$1,'); // Add letters to coords group
d = d.split(" "); // Split on space

var coords = [];

for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    var coordString = d[i];
    var coordArray = coordString.split(",");

    var coord = {
        x: coordArray[coordArray.length - 2],
        y: coordArray[coordArray.length - 1]
    };

    if (coordArray.length > 2) {
        coord.path = coordArray[0];
    }

    coords.push(coord);

}
```

You can see it working in **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzhxtgu6/)**.

Comment: Can't see my path sir :( How can I make it viewable?

Comment: In your question you asked just for it as a JSON.  Have a look in the console for the JSON.

Comment: How to look for console? I'm not using firebug.

Answer (score 0):

You can head over here, we have both node packages and API, as well as a simple web interface.

```
Github: https://github.com/Rexfont/svgJson
```

The API instruction is given in there as well
example:

```
svgjson({data: 'filepath/string', web: false, file: true, remove: true, output: true, filename: 'example.txt'})
```

You can use the API if you wish to use it multiple times on web or use the npm for node